# Reversible endothermic reaction

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Is there an endothermic reaction that is reversible simple by adding heat?  For instance, can I put chemicals in an enclosed tube that will react to release heat, then I can add heat and reverse the reaction so that it will begin again?

Comment: Endothermic reactions are reversed by REMOVING heat. You may want to fix your question.

Comment: So you basically want a heat battery. Usually it's best to make use of phase changes (a physical process), but another chemical option which can be accessed in simple conditions is [the equilibrium between nitrogen dioxide and dinitrogen tetroxide](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/158903/1499). I suppose the best possible heat battery will be represented by a process with a very high $\Delta S$, such that even a very large $\Delta H$ will still result in a process with $\Delta G$ close to zero in reasonable conditions (which, once again, sounds like a phase change near ambient conditions)

Comment: Very much not by coincidence, you are running into the idea of refrigeration (or heat pump) cycles. It's possible there are some niche applications of chemical reactions in refrigeration/heat pump cycles, so you could find an example there.

Comment: "put chemicals in a tube to **release** heat: that's **exothermic**!

Answer (score 6):

1. Would crystallization qualify? Try a [$\ce{NaCH3COO·3H2O}$ (sodium acetate) hand-warmer](https://www.sciencefocus.com/science/how-do-re-usable-hand-warmers-work/). Easily done, and comparatively safe as a demonstration in classroom, or even at home.
2. $\ce{Ca(OH)2 <=> CaO + H2O}$. This might be difficult to use as a demo, because high temperatures are involved. Though I could *describe* a borosilicate apparatus with two connected flasks, one containing the $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ to be heated, the other at room temperature to capture evaporated water to be mixed back on cooling, construction of one robust enough to survive the heat involved might be tricky.
3. Easiest to demonstrate would be an *electrochemical* reaction, i.e., a [secondary (storage) cell](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analytical_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Analytical_Chemistry)/Electrochemistry/Exemplars/Rechargeable_Batteries) such as lead-acid or NiCd cells. Though lead is cheap, and produces enough voltage from a single cell to light a red LED, cleanup of the toxic metal and compounds formed are a downside.

Answer (score 0):

Any reaction that reaches equilibrium is endothermic in one direction and exothermic in the other. This means that at equilibrium a change in heat content, with [change in equilibrium constant] or without [latent heat in a phase change] a change in temperature, will cause the reaction to establish a new equilibrium position.

Another approach is to isolate the oxidation and reduction halves of a reaction and make a cell. Now by applying an appropriate potential and adding energy the concentrations can be adjusted that the cell can supply electrical energy. This is a much more efficient method than changing the temperature. This approach is used daily by most of us to keep our cell phones operating.

The same effect should be possible by raising the temperature; unfortunately in raising the T the speed of side reactions is also increased; the phone will melt, the transistors will stop working, who knows what the lithium will do.